# Logical OR MongoDB NodeJS Query

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, logical-operators

How does one implement a logical OR on the same JSON field when querying Mongo from NodeJS?

In particular, I have the following line:

```
collection.find({"user":req.user.email, "parent._id":0}, function(err, activities){
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(activities);
});
```

How could I properly include entries such that "parent":{} is also allowed?

The following gives me an empty array:

```
collection.find({"user":req.user.email, "parent":{}, "parent._id":0}, function(err, activities){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(activities);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
collection.find({"user":req.user.email, $or:[{"parent._id":0},{"parent":{}}]}, function(err, activities){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(activities);
});
```