# How to find data based on sub-field name in MongoDB using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There is a sub-field called 'name' in MongoDB Collection (User):

```
[
{
    "teacher": {
        "name": "Alex",
        "email": "alex@domain.com"
    },
    "waiter": {
        "name": "Feliks",
        "email": "feliks@domain.com"
    },
    "pilot": [
    {
        "name": "Sam",
        "email": "sam@domain.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "alice",
        "email": "alice@domain.com"
    }
    ],
},
{
    "teacher": {
        "name": "max",
        "email": "max@domain.com"
    },
    "waiter": {
        "name": "Sam",
        "email": "sam@domain.com"
    },
    "pilot": [
    {
        "name": "richard",
        "email": "richard@domain.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "alice",
        "email": "alice@domain.com"
    }
    ],
}
]
```

How can I find data based on the field 'name'. For example, when I'm looking for 'Sam', it should return me the all documents since 'Sam' is in "waiter" and "pilot" in first and second documents respectively.

I cannot do something like:

```
User.find({"teacher.name": "Sam", "waiter.name": "Sam", "pilot.name": "Sam" })
```

This will return me nothing as it is an AND logic. What I need is an OR logic.

Comment: Have you tried using `$or`?

Comment: @Joe, I guess it's what I am looking for

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274135/logical-or-mongodb-nodejs-query and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$or` operator.
So the query should look like this:

```
User.find({ $or: [
                  { "teacher.name": "Sam" }, 
                  { "waiter.name": "Sam" }, 
                  { "pilot.name": "Sam" }
                 ] 
          });
```

Read [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) for me details.